# Split java string using regex then store into stack

Tags: java, regex, lexer

There is some error in my logic for splitting string based on regex. The goal is create a tokenizer for the python syntax. I have four simple regex written; digits, floats, operators, and variables. I want to extract the first set of the four regex listed above into a string and then push it to my stack.

```java
String s = "123+abc+123abc";
String allRegex = String.format("%s|%s|%s|%s", digit, floats, operators, variable);
Pattern allRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(allRegex);
Matcher matchString = allRegexPattern.matcher(s);

int group = 1;
while (s != null)
{
    if (group == 5)
        group = 1;
    if (matchString.find())
    {
        String temp = matchString.group(group);
        if (temp != null)
        {
            tokens.add(temp);
            s = s.replace(temp, "");
        }
        else
            group++;

    }
}

//Expecting ["123","+","abc","+","123abc"] in my stack
```

Right now, the code is running infinitely..

Comment: Order matters to RegExp's `|`.

You might want to put floats first since floats like `-123.456e+2` can contain substrings that are runs of digits ("123", "456") and operators ("-", "+") and variables ("e").

Comment: This looks like a lexing problem.  Have you considered using Java's StringTokenizer or a parser generator like Antlr?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I did try using StringTokenizer, however, I couldn't find a proper way for getting the correct result. I tried to split my string using example: r = s.split(digit), but that would put all the digits in the string inside r.

Comment: You're checking for `s != null`, but `s` is never set to null. Assuming the code in the loop works, `s` will become an empty string, which is not considered null. You might want to check `s.isEmpty()` instead.

Comment: @DhruvMurarka Tried that, no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
public Stack<String> getStack(String expression){
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-z]+|\\+|\\*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
    while(matcher.find()) {
       stack.push(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println(stack.toString());
    return stack;
}
```

Comment: `matcher.group()` only returns the first group. I have four different groups of regex, I want to check the string for each group and add each group to the stack.

Comment: If you pass "123+abc+123abc" to the function it will return the stack with all groups. Output is : `[123, +, abc, +, 123abc]`.

Comment: I do not get that with the regex I have.  I am trying to group each digits, floats, parenthesis, operators (including =), and variable names. 
`(\(|\))|(\d*\.\d*|\.\d*)|(\d*)|([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*)|(\+|-|\*{1,2}|\/{1,2}|%|=)`
Any changes I can make?

Comment: Got everything figured out, this helped very well!